# I don't receive FCM push notification from android to iOS

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I don't receive FCM push notification from android on iOS:

From Android to Android: It's ok.

From iOS to iOS: It's ok.

From iOS to Android: It's ok.

From Android to iOS: Doesn't work.

I guess, it's maybe my Kotlin code the suspect:
Here's my code:

`NotificationService` Class:

```
Class NotificationService: FirebaseMessagingService() {

...

   fun sendNotification(notification: PushNotification) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            val response = RetrofitInstance.api.postNotification(notification)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                println("RESPONSE : ${Gson().toJson(response)}")
                println("OK")
            }else {
                println("RESPONSE ERROR: ${response.errorBody().toString()}")
            }
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            println("ERROR: ${e.toString()}")
        }
    }

    fun send(title: String, message: String, token: String) {
        PushNotification(NotificationData(title, message), token).also {

            sendNotification(it)
        }
    }
}
```

I call the function `send()` like this `NotificationService().send("My title", "My message", "A_GIVEN_TOKEN")`

Here is `RetrofitInstance` Class

```
class RetrofitInstance {

    companion object {
        private val retrofit by lazy {
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL) //BASE_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com"
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }

        val api by lazy {
            retrofit.create(NotificationAPI::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `NotificationAPI` class:

```
interface NotificationAPI {

    @Headers("Authorization: key=$SERVER_KEY", "Content-Type:$CONTENT_TYPE") //CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json"
    @POST("fcm/send")
    suspend fun postNotification(
        @Body notification: PushNotification
    ): Response<ResponseBody>
}
```

Here is my `PushNotification` DataClass

```
data class PushNotification (
    val data: NotificationData,
    val to: String)
```

Here is my `NotificationData` class

```
data class NotificationData (
    val title: String,
    val message: String
)
```

My `AppDelegate` in Xcode :

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
          //FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions,completionHandler: {_, _ in })
                  // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        return true
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
      
    guard let fcmToken = fcmToken else {return}

      let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      
     //DOESEN'T PASS HERE
        guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any] else {return}
        guard let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String: String] else {return}
        guard let title = alert["title"] else {return}
        guard let body = alert["body"]  else {return}

        let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1007
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID)

        
        print("TITLE : ", title)
        print("BODY : ", body)
        
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("ERROOOOR: ", error)
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        //PASS HERE
        let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1007
               // to play sound
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID)
        print(notification.request.content.userInfo)
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
        
}
```

How I can receive FCM push notifications on iOS from android ?
Can you answer with code example please ? I don't understand very well all this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally find an another method to send a push notification to a specific token with kotlin and Firebase and Volley library.

Here's the method:

```
fun send(title: String, message: String, token: String, context: Context) {
        val serverKey = YOUR_SERVER_KEY // Replace YOUR_SERVER_KEY by your API key Firebase

        val notification = JSONObject()
        notification.put("title", title)
        notification.put("body", message)

        val data = JSONObject()
        data.put("key1", "value1")
        data.put("key2", "value2")

        val message = JSONObject()
        message.put("to", token)
        message.put("notification", notification)
        message.put("data", data)

        val request = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
            message,
            Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
               
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
               
            }) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                headers["Authorization"] = "key=$serverKey"
                return headers
            }
        }
      Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request)
}
```